# How to use dplyr group_by() to group samples by n number of days to get the n-day average of the sample results in R?

Tags: dplyr, mean, summarize

I have used group_by() in the past to calculate the weekly, monthly, and annual averages of my sample results. However, I am having trouble figuring out a solution for situations where I need the 4-day or 10-day average.

Here is my sample data:

```
    data_test <- tibble('WBID' = c("10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A",
                                   "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A",
                                   "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A",
                                   "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A"),
                  'Station' = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                   "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                                   "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",
                                   "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                  'SampleDate' = c('2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                   '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                   '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                   '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06'),
                  'Result' = c(7, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 
                               1, 7, 9, 3, 9, 4, 1, 9, 3, 6, 4, 3, 
                               8, 2, 9, 7, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 8,
                               4, 1, 7, 8, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3))
```

Here is the code that has worked for me previously when calculating the weekly mean:

```
#Averages the data for each Station (7-day avg)
data_test <- data_test %>% group_by(WBID, Station, Week = format(SampleDate, "%Y-%U")) %>% 
  mutate(Result_7day = mean(Result))
```

How do I use group_by() to group the SampleDate by n number of days so I can calculate the n-day average?

Here are my desired results when n = 4:

```
data_test <- tibble('WBID' = c("10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A",
                               "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A",
                               "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A",
                               "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A"),
                    'Station' = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                  "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                                  "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",
                                  "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                    'SampleDate' = c('2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                     '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                     '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                     '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06'),
                    'Result' = c(7, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 
                                 1, 7, 9, 3, 9, 4, 1, 9, 3, 6, 4, 3, 
                                 8, 2, 9, 7, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 8,
                                 4, 1, 7, 8, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3),
                    'Result_4day' = c(4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3, 4.5,
                                      5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6.25, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 5.5, 4,
                                      6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 5.25, 6.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 2.5, 4.25,
                                      5, 5, 5, 5, 4.25, 5.25, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3.75, 3.5))
```

It would be ideal if this could be done within group_by() but if not, any solution would be helpful. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: As some of the answers have said, there are some solutions that wouldn't work if there aren't consecutive dates. This does pose a problem for my case since I can expect there to be gaps in dates for the data. I was thinking one way around this would be to split the data and filter for data that are within plus/minus 4 days of each other, average those, and then rejoin with the data that wasn't plus/minus 4 days of each other.

Comment: Should it be a 4-day rolling average or a 4-day interval average? The way you describe grouping and compare it to weekly & monthly avg would suggest the latter, but desired results include rolling values.

Comment: And there seems to be a sort of anomaly in desired results, `Result_4day` for rows 37. .. 40 is 7.5, though that group average for (4, 1, 7, 8) should be 5.0

Comment: @margusl You are right. I manually inputted my desired output so that was a mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`silder::slide_index()` is one option for rolling calculation relative to an index. `SampleDate`, once converted to `Date`, is used as an index here. The window ends at the current index and goes back for three days.

To match the desired output, only complete 4-day window averages are calculated, resulting `NA` values are filled with next results. For date sequences less than four days, this will pose a problem as values from somewhat distant time windows will fill those `NA`s.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(slider)

result <- data_test %>% 
  mutate(SampleDate = as.Date(SampleDate)) %>% 
  group_by(WBID, Station) %>% 
  # find mean only for complete 4-day windows, 
  # use SampleDate for index and .before = lubridate::days(3) to look back
  # up to 3 days from current index
  mutate(Result_4day = slide_index_dbl(Result, SampleDate, 
                                       # find mean only for complete 4-day groups
                                       ~ if_else(length(.x) < 4, NA_real_, mean(.x)),
                                       .before = lubridate::days(3))) %>% 
  fill(Result_4day, .direction = "up") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```r
print(result, n = 48)
#> # A tibble: 48 × 5
#>    WBID  Station SampleDate Result Result_4day
#>    <chr> <chr>   <date>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 10A   A       2010-03-01      7        4.25
#>  2 10A   A       2010-03-02      7        4.25
#>  3 10A   A       2010-03-03      2        4.25
#>  4 10A   A       2010-03-04      1        4.25
#>  5 10A   A       2010-03-05      5        3.75
#>  6 10A   A       2010-03-06      7        3.75
#>  7 10A   A       2011-03-01      7        3.75
#>  8 10A   A       2011-03-02      1        3.75
#>  9 10A   A       2011-03-03      5        3.75
#> 10 10A   A       2011-03-04      2        3.75
#> 11 10A   A       2011-03-05      4        3   
#> 12 10A   A       2011-03-06      7        4.5 
#> 13 11A   B       2010-03-01      1        5   
#> 14 11A   B       2010-03-02      7        5   
#> 15 11A   B       2010-03-03      9        5   
#> 16 11A   B       2010-03-04      3        5   
#> 17 11A   B       2010-03-05      9        7   
#> 18 11A   B       2010-03-06      4        6.25
#> 19 11A   B       2011-03-01      1        4.75
#> 20 11A   B       2011-03-02      9        4.75
#> 21 11A   B       2011-03-03      3        4.75
#> 22 11A   B       2011-03-04      6        4.75
#> 23 11A   B       2011-03-05      4        5.5 
#> 24 11A   B       2011-03-06      3        4   
#> 25 12A   D       2010-03-01      8        6.5 
#> 26 12A   D       2010-03-02      2        6.5 
#> 27 12A   D       2010-03-03      9        6.5 
#> 28 12A   D       2010-03-04      7        6.5 
#> 29 12A   D       2010-03-05      3        5.25
#> 30 12A   D       2010-03-06      6        6.25
#> 31 12A   D       2011-03-01      1        1.25
#> 32 12A   D       2011-03-02      1        1.25
#> 33 12A   D       2011-03-03      1        1.25
#> 34 12A   D       2011-03-04      2        1.25
#> 35 12A   D       2011-03-05      6        2.5 
#> 36 12A   D       2011-03-06      8        4.25
#> 37 10A   C       2010-03-01      4        5   
#> 38 10A   C       2010-03-02      1        5   
#> 39 10A   C       2010-03-03      7        5   
#> 40 10A   C       2010-03-04      8        5   
#> 41 10A   C       2010-03-05      1        4.25
#> 42 10A   C       2010-03-06      5        5.25
#> 43 10A   C       2011-03-01      3        4   
#> 44 10A   C       2011-03-02      4        4   
#> 45 10A   C       2011-03-03      6        4   
#> 46 10A   C       2011-03-04      3        4   
#> 47 10A   C       2011-03-05      2        3.75
#> 48 10A   C       2011-03-06      3        3.5
```

Input data:

```r
data_test <- tibble('WBID' = c("10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A",
                               "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A", "11A",
                               "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A",
                               "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A", "10A"),
                    'Station' = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                  "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                                  "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",
                                  "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                    'SampleDate' = c('2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                     '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                     '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06',
                                     '2010-03-01','2010-03-02', '2010-03-03','2010-03-04','2010-03-05','2010-03-06','2011-03-01','2011-03-02','2011-03-03','2011-03-04','2011-03-05','2011-03-06'),
                    'Result' = c(7, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 
                                 1, 7, 9, 3, 9, 4, 1, 9, 3, 6, 4, 3, 
                                 8, 2, 9, 7, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 8,
                                 4, 1, 7, 8, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>